# Running Java process as Service in Linux

Tags: java, linux, service, rhel, tcsh

I need to run a Java process as a service in (Red Hat 6.4) Linux  (It needs to run at boot time and stay up).  I have it mostly working, except for it doesn't seem to status correctly in the "Service Configuration" window.

To illustrate, I made a simple Java program:

```
package service;

public class JavaService {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        System.out.println("Starting Java-Service");
        while(true){

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Java-Service is still running..");
        }
    }
}
```

I jarred that up, and put it at this location:  /opt/service/lib

Then, I created this script: /opt/service/bin/run_java_service

```
#!/bin/tcsh
#
# chkconfig: 2345 80 30
# description: java-service Service

setenv JAVA_SERVICE_HOME /opt/service
setenv CLASSPATH $JAVA_SERVICE_HOME/lib/JavaService.jar

setenv SERVICE_PID  `ps aux | grep JavaService | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`;

if ( (stop == $1  || restart == $1)) then
    echo "java-service stop";
    kill -9 $SERVICE_PID
    setenv SERVICE_PID
endif

if ( start == $1 || restart == $1 ) then
    if($SERVICE_PID) then
        echo "java-service is already running"
    else
        echo "java-service start";
        java service.JavaService&
    endif
endif

if (status == $1) then
    if($SERVICE_PID) then
        echo "java-service (pid $SERVICE_PID) is running...";
    else
        echo "java-service is stopped";
    endif
endif
```

I then created a symlink to this in the /etc/rc.d/init.d directory and added it to the chkconfig:

```
sudo ln –s /opt/service/bin/run_java_service /etc/rc.d/init.d/java-service
sudo chkconfig --add java-service
```

At this point, commands like this work as expected from the command line:

```
sudo service java-service stop
sudo service java-service start
sudo service java-service status
```

The problem is that things aren't statusing correctly in the "Service Configuration" dialog.  For instance, in this screenshot, I have clicked the "Stop Button" and it still shows as "plugged in".

[image]

What piece of the puzzle am I missing?

Comment: what user is starting the job and what users is clicking stop ?

Comment: root starts the job, and root stops the job

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [jsvc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html) from apache.  Tomcat use it to be launched as a service.